# Combing Hadoop and Elasticsearch

Tags: hadoop, jar, elasticsearch, centos, kibana

I'm trying to find an easy way to combine my hadoop cluster (I'm using cloudera manager CDH5.3) with the elasticSearch and so on.
I found that to do that; I have to install ElasticSearch in a different cluster, uploading the ElasticSearch library (I'll be using hive and pig) to combine the ES with my cluster !
Well it appears simple. But hey, I'm not a centos 6.6 expert! 
I have NO CLUE how that can be done

1. How do I import the specific jars via centos6.6 command line and where do I put them?
2. How to make my cluster see the ES
3. how combine the 2 hadoop and ES clusters using the imported jars?

Comment: Which HortonWorks documentation are you talking about? can you provide the link?

Comment: It doesn't exactly match the use case you've described, but here is a blog post I wrote about using Elasticsearch and Apache Spark together. Maybe it will help. http://blog.qbox.io/elasticsearch-in-apache-spark-python